# Change resources in other Win32-dll/exe

Tags: c#, .net

There is a [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) program which allow to change the resources in the other win32(64) dll and exe files.

I need to do the same thing, but programmaticaly. Is it possible to do it using .Net framework?  What is the good starting point to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use the [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [EndUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinApi functions, try [this page](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/BeginUpdateResource.html?diff=y) to check the pinvoke .Net signature of these functions, also you can check this project [ResourceLib](http://resourcelib.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Anolis.Resourcer](http://anolis.codeplex.com/). It seems to be the thing you need

> A ResHacker clone developed as a testbed for Anolis.Core and to replace ResHacker (because ResHacker doesn't support x64, XN Resource Editor (ResHacker's spiritual sequel) doesn't support multiple-language resources and crashes a lot, and other utilities rest cost actual money. It has a powerful yet simplified UI that doesn't duplicate commands or confuse the users with special-case handlers (which ResHacker and XN have in spades).

Answer (score 0):

The author points to another tool "[XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm)" which comes with source code (although Delphi, not .NET).

This should be enough to see which functions being used and use the .NET equivalent of them.

Answer (score 0):

Note that none of these will work if you're dealing with signed EXEs or DLLs.

Comment: Thanks for the info, btw do you know why?

Comment: Because once you change the resource, the signature won't match. And you can't sign again without the private key, which you don't have.

Comment: I know that, I thought that you meant that we can't modify the resources in signed EXEs/DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I see it is not easy task, so I'll use [command line interface](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/47720-reshack-command-line-option/) of Resource Hacker.